# How to get all opened chromium tabs list for Linux in CLI?

Tags: google-chrome, awk, grep, command-line-interface, text-processing

I try this :

```
strings ~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session' | grep 'https?:'
```

but I get only one match. What's going on ? oO The output is newline `\n` delimited

I'm only be able to 'grep' with awk:

```
strings ~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session' | awk '/^https?:/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Grep** by default uses standard regular expressions.  Using either `egrep`, or `grep -E` allows you to use the same "extended regular expressions" syntax that **awk** uses.

```
strings ~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session' | grep -E '^https?:'
```

You could also use standard regular expressions:

```
strings ~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session' | grep '^https\?:'
```